# May one beautify his Payos?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, hair, payot-sideburns, beauty

*Rashi* (*B'reshis* 37:2) calls it an "an act of immaturity [to fix one's] hair (...) so he would look good".

Obviously, *payos* are made from hair, but they are not considered regular hair within *kabbala* (*k'lipos* that are to be removed).

The fact is that many orthodox Jews go to [great lengths](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66351/how-does-one-grow-long-peyos) in order to have long beautiful *payos*.

Question is if they have a status as *mitzva* item that exempts them from the problem *Rashi* speaks of.

Comment: Hi NBZ. This is a wonderful question! Is it possible for you to briefly explain Rashi's  rationale for calling the act of taking care of one's hair "immature." I will of course (?) do my own research on this topic  but since you appear to have at least some of the facts-on-hand......Thank you NBZ.

Comment: @JJLL  Your question would actually be a very good question too, so why not [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it? If I have understood right, it is seen as an effeminate thing to do. However, you may want to ask [msh210](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66810/guarding-payos-overnight?lq=1#comment187408_66810) instead of me. Also, remember to up-vote questions you consider good!

Comment: Considering tending to one's hair as being an effeminate act makes sense. (Not that I necessarily agree with it.) You are right about the up-vote NBZ. You got it. As far as asking my response as a question, I will wait a bit to see what responses/answers  your question receives. Again, great question NBZ.

Comment: אלו דברים שאין להם שיעור הפאה... :)

Comment: I would assume that Hidur Mitzvah would kick in. Although, we shouldn't follow the practice of the Egyptians, and to quote Yirmiyahu: עֶגְלָה יְפֵה פִיָּה מִצְרָיִם קֶרֶץ מִצָּפוֹן בָּא בָא. :)

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot It's not so clear that *hiddur mitzva* (à la "זה א-לי ואנוהו") would apply to a לא תעשה.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35677

Comment: First of all nice pun. I enjoyed the great lengths reference. How are you defining the hidur exactly? Beautiful b/c they are long or b/c they are curled when they are long? There are potential problems with begged isha if one uses hair curlers and shaping them has nothing to do with the mitzvah. If it is longer that is what you are going by for hidur, how is this a hidur of the mitzvah exactly?

Comment: @Dude Having a larger mitzva item is usually considered a hiddur, e.g. large esrog, havdalah light, menorah, kiddush cup, tzitzis, tallis (crown), mezuza, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Tosafos in Chagiga 7a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) - ד"ה והבכורים  - states that only items mentioned in the Mishna we say daily - *these are the items that have no measure* - are those items that doing more is a bigger Mitzva.

> **והבכורים אין לו שיעור לא למעלה ולא למטה.** הדר פריך בירושלמי רבי ברכיה בעי למה לא תנינן עפר לסוטה אפר פרה רוק יבמה דם צפור של מצורע א''ר יוסי לא אייתינן במתני' אלא דברים שהוא מוסיף עליהן ויש בעשייתן מצוה ואלו אע''פ שמוסיף עליהן אין בעשייתן מצוה:‏

For other Mitzvos one gets no extra points for increasing them. E.g. if the Yevama spits more, she has not done a bigger & better Mitzva.

If you look in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah קפ"א you will see that the peyos area ends at the bottom of the ear (if not higher).

The בית לחם יהודה adds that one should ensure that they do not grow into the beard area - which starts below the Payos area. He adds that the Ari z"l would trim his peyos every Friday, IIRC.

Since there's clearly no Mitzva-aspect to longer payos, (and the Ari z"l et. al. would say there's a problem with it, actually) it's hard to explain why beautifying the long payos would be a Mitzva.

That leaves us with Rashi.

Comment: Fun fact, the mishna you say daily, isn't actually the mishna. Its a combination of multiple mishnaot and a bereita in the talmud.

Also, the "peah" mentioned in the mishna, isn't just one sidelock :P

Comment: @avi - the first half is Mishna 1:1 in Peah: אֵלּוּ דְבָרִים  שֶׁאֵין לָהֶם שִׁעוּר. הַפֵּאָה , וְהַבִּכּוּרִים, וְהָרֵאָיוֹן, וּגְמִילוּת חֲסָדִים, וְתַלְמוּד תּוֹרָה - the second half starting with אֵלּוּ דְבָרִים שֶׁאָדָם אוֹכֵל  פֵּרוֹתֵיהֶן is a compendium, as you say.